# Writing a huge R dataframe into 4 separate files in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble/dataframe in R with about 206 million records and 5 columns. My system runs out of memory if I do any further analysis/computation on this data. Hence, I want to write this tibble into 4 separate csv files (to disk) of ~50 million records each (last one would be ~56 million) and proceed with further computation/analysis in 4 separate iterations. I searched a few threads on the web could not find any suitable to this usecase.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: do your splits into separate dataframes and then you can write each dataframe to a csv separately.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover My system doesn't have memory to hold these further splits as the master dataframe is already into memory. I need to write these to disks directly.

Comment: Can you save the whole file, then load - subset - save subset?

Comment: Have you tried something direct like `data.table::fwrite(your_data[1:5e7, ], "chunk_1.csv");`, then `data.table::fwrite(your_data[(5e7 + 1):10e7, ], "chunk_2.csv");`, then `data.table::fwrite(your_data[(10e7 + 1):15e7, ], "chunk_3.csv");`, etc.? Alternately you could write the whole thing to a single file and use arguments of your read-in function to only read in chunks of it (e.g. using the `skip` and `nrows` parameters of `data.table::fread`)

Comment: Definitely look at non-base packages to speed up the read/write. data.table's `fread` and `fwrite` are **very** good. If not that, at least use `readr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us know if your machine has the memory for the below. This is to achieve OP's goal (request) to split then save original `df` into 4 separate files

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

# dummy data
df <- data.table(row_id = 1:123)

# parameters
x <- nrow(df)  # nrow of df
y <- 4    # no. of splits

# create batch number
df[, batch := rep(1:y, each=x/y, length.out=x)]

# split
df <- split(df, by='batch')

# save as separate csv
lapply( df, \(i) fwrite(i, file = paste0( i[1][1,'batch'], '.csv')) )
```

Comment: I am surprised somewhat that `df <- split(df, ...)` doesn't (if only transiently) require both the split and unsplit copies of `df` to exist in memory simultaneously. I wonder if `fwrite` is slightly safer in this regard.

Comment: @MikaelJagan Both unsplit (df) & split (list) may have to exit transiently (tho can't be sure). By "safe" do u mean possible out of memory?
An alternative would be to `fwrite` in batches using row number indexing

Answer (score 0):

There are two base R approaches that you can try, if for some reason `data.table` is not an option. The first approach is to write the full data frame (here called `df`) to disk, free the memory occupied by `df`, then read and write the subsets one at a time using `readLines` and `writeLines`.

```r
nms <- names(df)
n <- nrow(df)

write.table(df, file = "df.csv", sep = ",", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
rm(df); gc(FALSE)

start <- seq(from = 1L, to = n, by = 5e+07L)
end <- c(start[-1L] - 1L, n)

rcon <- file("df.csv", "r")
for (i in seq_along(start)) {
    wcon <- file(sprintf("df_%d_%d.csv", start[i], end[i]), "w")
    cat(nms, wcon, sep = ",")
    cat("\n", wcon)
    writeLines(readLines(rcon, n = end[i] - start[i] + 1L), wcon)
    close(wcon)
}
close(rcon)
unlink("df.csv")
```

The second (probably much worse) approach is to write the variables in `df` to disk individually, free the memory occupied by `df`, then read the variables into memory one at a time as needed to construct and write the subsets.

```r
nms <- names(df)
n <- nrow(df)

for (nm in nms) {
    saveRDS(df[[nm]], file = paste0(nm, ".rds"))
}
rm(df); gc(FALSE)

start <- seq(from = 1L, to = n, by = 5e+07L)
end <- c(start[-1L] - 1L, n)

for (i in seq_along(start)) {
    l <- setNames(vector("list", length(nms)), nms)
    for (nm in nms) {
        l[[nm]] <- readRDS(paste0(nm, ".rds"))[start[i]:end[i]]
    }
    write.csv(l, file = sprintf("df_%d_%d.csv", start[i], end[i]), row.names = FALSE)
}
unlink(paste0(nms, ".rds"))
```

Ideally, you are running the above in a new R process with only `df` in the global environment.

Answer (score -1):

Apologies if this solution misses the mark, but I believe the below should work:

```
df %>% #name of dataframe
slice(1:5.0e7) %>% #first 50M rows
write_csv("file_a.csv") #save as csv
```

and repeat for the remaining sets just changing the reference for `slice()` and the file name in `write_csv()`